# VBA: Compile Error: Syntax Error when trying to use Cell.Replace VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hi I'm new to VBA and I've created a code to format my Table however I receive an error "Compile Error: Syntax Error" when trying to run it.
I have tried to look at the code but I can't seem to find what the issue is.

The first Cell.Replace section is highlighted red when I try to run it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub TableFormat()

    Cells.Replace What:="xl", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
        , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Cells.Replace What:="£", Replacement:="GBP", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Clear

    Columns("A:A").Delete
    Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is `FormulaVersion` a valid parameter? I don't see it in the MS help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace

Comment: `FormulaVersion` is new (guessing 2019, 365).  Just remove that and it should work.  On a side note I'd use `xlToLeft` from the last column - `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select`.  If there's gaps in row 1 `xlToRight` will stop at the first gap, or if there's no data in row 1 then it will select the last column and then try to offset by 1 column and throw an error.  On another side note - I wouldn't use SELECT at all and fully qualify the worksheet you're looking at.  `CELLS` on its own will look at whichever sheet in whichever file is currently active.